# AdMob native ad - hide close button

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I've got AdMob Express Native Ads and I would like to hide the close button - the one in the right corner by default.

The user goes through app content by clicking the next button, so he can just skip the ad in this way.

I want to hide the close button, because some users think that they have to do that in order to go forward - the close button is a bit misleading.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argement between you and Google declare some restrictions.

Some of them:

1. User have to understand that this banner is advertisment.
2. User can cancel this add he/she can make a complaint to the ad.
3. You cannot manipulate this extra elements. They must exist.
4. Banners should not interfere with the main elements of the app.

So, no way.